# How can i configure ingress and nginx ingress controller to send http traffic to port 80 and https traffic to 443 port, with the same host and path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a service for my app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app
  name: app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: "443"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: "80"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: app
```

and ingress:

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 200m
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.app.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: app
            servicePort: 443
```

and ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.25.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
            - --enable-ssl-passthrough
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            # www-data -> 33
            runAsUser: 33
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 10
```

The problem is that the ingress controller send's both http and https traffic to port 443. 
i want to configure it to be able to send http traffic to port 80 and https traffic to port 443. how can i do that? or there is a something i don't understand correctly?.

Comment: did u solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update a question to a bit more precise?

I can deduct in 2 cases.

1) If you want to send the same traffic to port 80 and 443?

2) You want traffic received on port 443 in ingress to send to port 80 to pod.

Still, I will give in short.

Case 1

It is not possible. you have to opt for istio etc which provide traffic mirroring.

Case 2

It is valid and used a lot called SSL offloading. for that, you have to remove below annotation and update ingress to send traffic on port 80 than 443.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

Comment: I want to send http traffic to port 80 and https traffic to port 443. I don't want the ingress to do the SSL offloading even though i know it's the preffered way. I have a web server behind the service that should do the SSL offloading.

Comment: http to 80 and https to 433 that is easy. you have a rule for 443 add rule for 80 it will work. 
```
  rules:
  - host: test.app.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: app
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: It does not work. still send's traffic to 443. because it's the first backed that matches.

Comment: can you add nginx service entry.? also if possible ngix.conf from pod

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: servicea
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: servicea
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: I asked how to traffic https to 443 and http to 80 and with the same host and path. your solution uses different path and both of them is routed to port 80.

Comment: try annotation : nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"